# Calling a method from a different class and not knowing the name of the object

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I am trying to call a method from one class that is contained in another class. However I do not know the object name to call, so I cannot use the command ClassName.objectName.methodName()

Also .this command does not work either since .this references objects within its own class.

I have tried numerous combinations of code but all gave me compiler errors.

This is the line that I am trying to run:

```
averageVector[i]=averageVector[i]+(FeatureVector.featureAt(i));
```

FeatureVector is the class that contains the object.

If you need more information let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Full codes as requested:

Class name: Cluster:

```
    public FeatureVector getCentroid(){
    int numberOfVectors;
    double [] averageVector;
    numberOfVectors=this.getSize();
    averageVector=new double [this.featureV[0].getSize()];

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfVectors;i++){
      averageVector[i]=averageVector[i]+(FeatureVector.this.featureAt(i));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<averageVector.length; i++){
      averageVector[i]=(averageVector[i]/numberOfVectors);
    }
    FeatureVector centroid = new FeatureVector (numberOfCentroids, averageVector);
    return FeatureVector.centroid;
  }
```

class FeatureVector:

```
class FeatureVector {
  private double [] elems;
//...

//constructor 
FeatureVector (String newName, double [] newElems){
    name=newName;
    double [] elems=new double [newElems.length];
      for (int i=0; i < newElems.length; i++){
      elems[i]=newElems[i];
}
```

and the method in FeatureVector:

```
 public double featureAt(int index){
    return elems[index];
  }
```

Comment: Can't you just call featureAt(i)? You might also try FeatureVector.this.featureat(i). Both of these suggestions assumes your inner class is non-static.

Comment: When trying FeatureVector.this.featureat(i) I get compiler error:  not an enclosing class: FeatureVector

Comment: You'll need to give more information I think, what are "features" you certainly at least have to have some expectations about the object.  Do you have an array of them? Is there only one? You don't need the object at all maybe, you can call a method in `FeatureVector` to return the object(s)?

Comment: Are you calling a static method or a member method?

Comment: In fact - why do you want to do that? It sounds like there is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: I am trying to read double values from an array contained in an object under FeatureVector. Calling FROM: different class, and assigning these values to an array (also double).

Comment: Could you please post the code of your 2 classes?

Comment: This is the method in FeatureVector:

`public double featureAt(int index){
    return elems[index]};`

Comment: elems is an array of double values that I am trying to access

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't grab the whole array at once?  something like `public double[] getFeatures() { return elems; }` ?  The reason you can't do what you want is because you are using the class name, if you made a FeatureVector object like: `FeatureVector fVec = new FeatureVector()` you could call `fVec.getFeatures()`.  If the class and method should truly be static, you could change `getFeatures()` and `elems` to a static method/var and call it as `FeatureVector.getFeatures()`.  Posting your code would probably make this pretty clear.

Comment: Maybe if I explain what I am trying to do overall, you may see a completely different approach. 
I need to copy values stored in an array under Class 1, under object. and paste them into Class 2, method 1, array.

Comment: @turbo. Calling fVec.getFeatures() would work if I knew the name of the object. I dont know the "fVec" part. The main method is calling this copying method and is referencing some object.

Comment: It's very unclear when you use numbers and the most basic terms of class/method.  I understand that you maybe don't want to reveal your source code, but can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I don't understand how you could not know/get the object name. Do you have a data structure filled with these objects or something?

Comment: Where is the `FeatureVector` that you are actually trying to access? Where do you create it?

Answer (score 0):

```
averageVector[i]=averageVector[i]+(FeatureVector.featureAt(i));
```

You're attempting to invoke featureAt() as a static method. That isn't how you have it declared. Instead of invoking it against the FeatureVector class, invoke it against an instance of that class.

(Note that the `FeatureVector.this.featureAt(i)` syntax is a different kettle of worms entirely. That's a special syntax used from an inner class to reference the outer-class object that owns it.)